# Is there a data structure that has ability to get collection of N greatest elements, implemented in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, treeset

There is TreeSet data structure in java that provides ability to get 1 greatest element. I need data structure that allows to get collection of N greatest elements.

I need smth like this:

```
GreatestN<Integer> greatest = new GreatestN<>(Arrays.asList(5, 2, 1, 7));
greatest.getN(2); // returns {1, 2}
greatest.getN(3); // returns {1, 2, 5}

greatest.add(0);
greatest.getN(2); // returns {0, 1}
```

Comment: You can sort a data structure, get an `Iterator` from it, and then get however many elements you need. Just remember to sort in descending order.

Comment: Of course I could:) But if data structure (that I'm asking) exists, I think it's better to use it.

Comment: You can get a descending iterator from a `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all answers and comments, especially  shmosel's ones:

> You can get a descending iterator from a `TreeSet`.

It looks like structure I'm asking doesn't exist, but it could be simple created:

```
public class TreeSetMy<E> extends TreeSet<E> {

    public ArrayList<E> getFirstN(int n) {
        if (n > this.size()) {
            n = this.size();
        }

        ArrayList<E> firstN = new ArrayList<>(n);
        Iterator iter = this.iterator();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            firstN.add((E) iter.next());
        }

        return firstN;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort your List and then pass the index value to get the greatest number.

```
    List<Integer> greatest = Arrays.asList(5, 2, 1, 7);
    Collections.sort(greatest); // By default sorts ascending 
    System.out.println(greatest.get(greatest.size()-1)); //will give you greatest element in the list.
    //System.out.println(greatest.get(greatest.size()-1-nthNumber));
    System.out.println(greatest.get(0));//will give you lowest element in the list.
```

Comment: Thank you, but your solution has to big time complexity. It sorts whole list before each get request. So complexity is `O( m * log(m) ), where m = list.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

`TreeSet` has methods to get subsets based on the value of the element (`headSet` and `tailSet`), but not by index. For index based approach you'll need to use a `List` and `subList()`.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5, 2, 1, 7);
list.sort();
List<Integer> topFive = list.subList(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution to your problem online that was already available so I wrote one.

If you want to just use the code you provided without modifying it, then add my code as a class in your project.

```
public class GreatestN <T extends Comparable<T>>{


    private List<T> list;

    public GreatestN(List newList){

        this.list = newList;

        Collections.sort(list);

    }

    public List getN(int numbers){

        List<T> returnList = new ArrayList();

        if(numbers>list.size()){
            numbers = list.size();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers; i++){

            returnList.add(this.list.get(i));

        }

        return returnList;
    }

    public void add(T t){

        list.add(0,t);

        Collections.sort(list);

    }

}
```